# Extracting last value of unique filtered column

Tags: mysql

As a beginner in MySQL I'm having some difficulties building a query. I want to extract the values of the second column (Fecha) in my table for every unique value in the first one (CodigoEst). My final goal is to know the last/most recent value of "Fecha".

My table looks like

[image]

Then I want to have the values of "Fecha" for any different value of "CodigoEst".

I have tried DISTINCT but this gives the list of unique values in CodigoEst, not the values in Fecha. I have also tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT `CodigoEst`,`Fecha` FROM temperatura_max ORDER BY `Fecha` DESC LIMIT 1
```

But this gives the last value of "Fecha" just for one value of "CodigoEst". Expected output would be something like

```
CodigoEst Fecha

7031      2010-10-31
8460      2012-01-15
3610      2010-12-31
```

where the values in "Fecha" are the most recent dates

Any suggestion would be welcome, thanks

Comment: Provide a sample of expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by CodigoEst and select max value

```
SELECT CodigoEst, MAX(fetcha) mostRecent FROM temperatura_max GROUP BY CodigoEst
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the MAX() to get the most recent data:

```
SELECT MAX(ColName) FROM Table
```

Or you can use:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(ColName) FROM Table
```

Comment: This just gives the last value in Fecha but what I need is the last value of Fecha for any unique CodigoEst